# User is not authorized to perform: connect:* on resource: * with an explicit deny"

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, postman, amazon-connect

I am trying to test Amazon Connect GetMetricData API in Postman. The issue I am facing is that API, in response, throws an error that says the user is not authorized to perform: connect:* on resource: * with an explicit deny."

I am wondering why I am getting this issue because the user I am using here holds full access of amazon connect. Not only Amazon Connect, also several other services' full access. You can see the issue in the following picture.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Can you show the resource policy for the Amazon Connect? This looks like the problem lies there. Even if your user has full access from identity-based policy, if your resource-based policy (Policy on Connect resource) has the explicit deny, you will be denied access

Comment: I am getting the same issue, have you got this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem myself too. The issue that I had was the keys in the JSON payload body weren't inside the double quotes `""`.

This error message looks to me like it can't identify any action or resource, so I don't think it should be related to any error-configured identity-based policy.

The error message itself isn't really descriptive about the error. I would suggest that if people encounter same problem in the future, make sure to double check on the payload body if you don't find any problem in the identity-based policy.

Comment: This saved me from going down an IAM rabbit hole!

Answer (score 0):

This error typically indicates that there is an IAM policy that explicitly denies the action that you're trying to perform, so you should check the policies assigned to your IAM user `qayyum` as a first step. If you don't find any policies with a deny statement for `connect`, you can try to add the following policy to your user. This policy explicitly allows GetMetricData API actions

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "connect:GetMetricData",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```