# User is not authorized to perform connect:* on resource: * with an explicit deny

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-connect

I'm trying to get real time metrics using Amazon connect API service . But **metrics** functions in connect API throws **User is not authorized to perform** error.[image]

This User have full access to amazon connect. I have checked for deny polices there is no deny policy attached with this user. I can get other data like **ListAgentStatuses**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74435342/13126651

Comment: Hi @JatinMehrotra thanks for the response I have tried that but not working